# Yii2: Rules unicle наоборот

Tags: yii2

Как в yii2 вывести ошибку если значение наоборот не совпадает со значением из базы данных?

**Я хочу вывести ошибку, если user не найден в базе данных.**

Пример вывода ошибки если значения совпадают. Что нужно модифицировать?

```
  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['user', 'unique', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'message' => 'Имя пользователя уже занято'],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Нашел способ - это написать свой валидатор, но может быть есть уже встроенный?

Comment: Конечно есть. Ниже уже дали ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется вашу проблему может решить валидатор `exist`.
Вот ссылка на гайд на русском: http://yiiframework.domain-na.me/doc/guide/2.0/ru/tutorial-core-validators#exist